# Можно ли откатить последнее обновление для Office 365?

Tags: ms-access, office365

После последнего обновления MS Office365, перестали запускаться базы Access с ошибкой:

> Не удается открыть базу данных из-за ошибки чтения ее VBA-проекта.
>   База данных может быть открыта, только если сначала удалить
>   VBA-проект.

Не хочется держать 2 версии Access'a и, при каждой такой ошибке, вручную копировать код модулей из файла открытого в "старой" версии в "новую".

Comment: Вы уверены, что это именно обновление виновато? Такое обычно появляется при повреждении базы. Все базы перестали открываться? Если да, то, скорее всего это поврежден офис. Нужно его переустановить с предварительным полным удалением. Штатная процедура удаления не все удаляет, поищите сторонние средства удаления.

Comment: Не все. Одна база перестала и в коллег выборочно перестали работать. Я думаю перекомпилировался какой-то компопент и в новой версии такая проблема. Несколько обновлений назад была проблема, что в 13 версии експорт в xls работает, в 365 - нет.